# Asymptotic behaviour of $\displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\log(n)}{n}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logarithms, asymptotics, divergent-series

This is my first question, I hope I won't make too many mistakes.

I have been given this question as an exercise, but I am struggling to find the solution. I have to calculate the asymptotic behaviour of $\displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\log(n)}{n}$.
I have tried to apply the partial sums formula, which is:

Let $\phi \in C^1(0,\infty)$, $\{a_n\} \subset \mathbb{C}$,

$\displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x} a_n\phi(n) = A(x)\phi(x) - \int_1^x A(u)\phi'(u)\,du$, where
$A(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x} a_n$.

I have decided to put $a_n = 1$, and $\frac{\log(n)}{n} = \phi(n)$. In this way, I obtain

$\displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{\log(n)}{n} = \left[x\right]\frac{\log(x)}{x} - \int_1^x \frac{(1 - \log(u))}{u^2} \left[u\right] du$

$= \log(x)-\frac{\left\{x\right\}\log(x)}{x}-\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{u-\left\{u\right\}}{u^2} du + \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\log(u)(u-\left\{u\right\})}{u^2} du$

$=\log(x)-\frac{\left\{x\right\}\log(x)}{x}-\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{1}{u} du + \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\left\{u\right\}}{u^2} du+ \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\log(u)}{u} du - \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\log(u)\left\{u\right\}}{u^2} du$

$=\log(x)-\frac{\left\{x\right\}\log(x)}{x}-\log(x) + \log(1)+ \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\left\{u\right\}}{u^2} du+ \frac{1}{2}\log^2(x)-\frac{1}{2}\log^2(1)- \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\log(u)\left\{u\right\}}{u^2} du$

$=-\frac{\left\{x\right\}\log(x)}{x}+\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\left\{u\right\}}{u^2} du+ \frac{1}{2}\log^2(x)- \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\log(u)\left\{u\right\}}{u^2} du$.

Then, $-\frac{\left\{x\right\}\log(x)}{x}=O\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right)$,

$\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\left\{u\right\}}{u^2} du=O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$,

and $ - \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\log(u)\left\{u\right\}}{u^2} du= O\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right)$

In the end, I obtain that the sum is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\log^2(x) + O\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right)$.
Then I have tried to plot my result to check it, but it doesn't seem a correct extimation. I would like to know if I am doing something wrong or if there is another approach to the problem. Thank you

Edit: I think that the last two errors are wrong.
$\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\left\{u\right\}}{u^2} du \leq \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{{1}}{u^2}=-\frac{1}{x}+1=O\left({1}\right)$,

and $ - \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\log(u)\left\{u\right\}}{u^2} du\leq \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{\log(u)}{u^2} du= 1- \frac{1}{x}-\frac{\log(x)}{x} = O\left(1\right)$

So I would write that the sum is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\log^2(x) + O\left(1\right)$.
Thanks for your patience

Comment: "After some calculations"? How are we supposed to help you to spot the mistake if you don't show those calculations?

Comment: Unless I've missed something, if you use the proof of the integral comparison test (see for example the standard proof that $\sum_{n\le x} \frac{1}{n} = \log(x) + O(1)$), then since $\log(x) / x$ is eventually decreasing, you should similarly get that $\sum_{n\le x} \frac{\log(n)}{n} = (\log(x))^2 + O(1)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler That's not the correct asymptotic behavior.

Comment: @jjagmath, I am sorry, I will edit my question and include my calculations

Comment: @jiagmath Oh, right, I of course forgot a constant factor on the $(\log(x))^2$ term.

Comment: You seem to be missing a factor of $2$ so $\frac12(\log(x))^2$ seems a better approximation: for very large $x$, you could do even better subtracting about $0.0728$ and some varying term decreasing in magnitude

Comment: @DietrichBurde That is the summation technique he is using

Comment: @Henry you are right, I will add it! Thank you

Comment: First of all *Welcome to the site !* I gave much more terms than required in order you be able to generate easily upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Let me tell you something that makes nearly all such problems (at a basic level) straightforward without having to apply partial summation (Abel summation formula) directly.

**Theorem**. *If $a_n$ and $b_n$ are sequences of positive numbers and $a_n \sim b_n$ with $\sum_{n \geq 1} b_n = \infty$, then $\sum_{n \leq N} a_n \sim \sum_{n \leq N} b_n$ as $N \to \infty$*.

**Proof**.  Left to the reader.  It's a nice exercise.

Clearly it's not important that the sequence starts at $n = 1$ in this theorem.  Any starting point is fine.

Let's see how the theorem lets us replace sums with integrals to make asymptotic estimates under mild (and practical) conditions.

When $f(t)$ is a continuous positive function that is monotonic for large $t$ and $f(n) \sim f(n+1)$ as $n \to \infty$, we have
$$
f(n) \sim \int_n^{n+1} f(t)\,dt
$$
by making upper and lower bound estimates on the integral using $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$. Since
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \int_n^{n+1} f(t)\,dt = \int_1^{N+1} f(t)\,dt,
$$
if $\int_1^\infty f(t)\,dt = \infty$ we can use the theorem with $a_n = f(n)$ and $b_n= \int_n^{n+1} f(t)\,dt$ to obtain
$$
\sum_{n\leq N} f(n) \sim \int_1^{N+1}f(t)\,dt.
$$
It's unimportant that the summing and integrating starts at $1$. It could start at $2$, $3$, and so on.

**Example**.  Let $f(t) = (\log t)/t$ for $t \geq 2$. This is continuous, positive, and monotonic for $t \geq 3$, and
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\log t}{t}\,dt = \left.\frac{1}{2}(\log t)^2\right|_1^\infty = \infty,
$$
so as $N \to \infty$ in $\mathbf Z$,
$$
\sum_{n \leq N} \frac{\log n}{n} \sim \int_1^{N+1} \frac{\log t}{t}\,dt = \left.\frac{1}{2}(\log t)^2\right|_1^{N+1} = \frac{1}{2}(\log(N+1))^2.
$$
Since $\log(N+1) \sim \log N$, the above estimate implies
$$ 
\sum_{n \leq N} \frac{\log n}{n} \sim \frac{1}{2}(\log N)^2,
$$
and since $\log x \sim \log \lfloor x\rfloor$, we also obtain
$$
\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\log n}{n} \sim \frac{1}{2}(\log x)^2
$$
as $x \to \infty$ in $\mathbf R$.

**Remark**. This way of using the theorem above makes it really easy to find asymptotic estimates for partial sums in simple situations without having to think too hard.  But it does not provide lower-order terms in the estimates.  For that, you'll want to use partial summation.

**Exercise**. Show by the same method that for each $\alpha > 0$,
$$
\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{(\log n)^\alpha}{n} \sim \frac{1}{\alpha+1}(\log x)^{\alpha+1}
$$
as $x \to \infty$. In fact, the work should apply for $\alpha > -1$, not just $\alpha > 0$. (It would not make sense when $\alpha = -1$.)

Comment: While your first sentence is true, it's also true that these types of problems are usually used to practice using the partial summation method, and your answer of "don't use it" doesn't really help or answer the question of "where did OP get wrong"

Comment: @GarethMa I agree that such problems are a standard application of partial summation, but it does illustrate that if the goal is *only* to get an asymptotic estimate (and not some lower-order terms too, at least up to a $O$-estimate), then more efficient methods are available. I was very happy when I first became aware of this other way of working out asymptotic estimates on sums (when it works).

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that
$$
1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n=\ln n+\gamma+o(1)
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, we can write that
$$
f(m)=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\ln n}n \asymp \sum_{n=1}^m \frac1n\left[1+\frac12+...+\frac1n-\gamma\right]
=-\gamma \sum_{n=1}^m \frac1n +\frac12\left[\left(\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1n\right)^2-\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1{n^2}\right]
=\frac{1+o(1)}2\left(\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1n\right)^2
$$
hence $f(m)\sim \frac12 (\ln m)^2$.

Comment: When you express $\ln n$ using the harmonic numbers, $\gamma$ should get a minus sign, i.e., $\ln n \sim 1+1/2+\ldots + 1/n -\gamma$.

Comment: Thanks @Gary, corrected!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Abel-Plana formula, Eq.(2.10.2)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10)
$$\sum_{n=a}^x f(n)=\int_a^x f(x)dx+\frac{1}{2}f(a)+\frac{1}{2}f(x)-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im f(a+it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt+\hat{R}$$

where $\hat{R}$ is the remainder representing the last two terms in the second line of [Eq.(2.10.2)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10).

Let $$f(t)=\frac{\ln t}{t}$$

then the remainder $\hat{R}\sim o\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)$ when $x\rightarrow\infty$ for our choice of $f(t)$.

Set $a=1$, we get

$$f(1+it)=\frac{\ln(1+it)}{1+it}=\frac{\ln\sqrt{1+t^2}+i\arctan t}{1+it}$$

The imaginary part:

$$\Im f(1+it)=\arctan t-\frac{t}2\cdot\ln(1+t^2)$$

It is easy to show the integral converges, hence it equals some constant $C$.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im f(a+it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan t}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt-\int_0^\infty \frac{t\cdot\ln(1+t^2)}{2(e^{2\pi t}-1)}dt=C$$

So for large $x$, we get

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{\ln n}{n}\sim\int_1^x \frac{\ln t}{t}dt+C+\frac{\ln x}{2x}=\frac{1}2\ln^2(x)+C+\frac{\ln x}{2x}}$$

If we consider the leading order in the remainder $\hat{R}$, we can get

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{\ln n}{n}\sim\frac{1}2\ln^2(x)+C+\frac{1}2\cdot\frac{\ln x}{x}-\frac{1}{12}\cdot\frac{\ln x}{x^2}+\frac{1}{12}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}+\dots}$$

Comment: Note that $C=\gamma_1=-0.0728158454836767248605863758749\ldots$ is a [Stieltjes constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants).

Comment: Thank you very much! @Gary

Answer (score 1):

*To give more than the asymptotics*

Since
$$\int_1^x \frac {\log(n)}n \,dn=\frac{1}{2}\log ^2(x)$$
using Euler-MacLaurin summation formula, we have
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{\log(n)}{n}=C+\frac{\log ^2(x)}{2}+\frac{\log (x)}{2
   x}-\frac{\log (x)-1}{12 x^2}+\frac{6 \log (x)-11}{720
   x^4}-\frac{60 \log (x)-137}{15120
   x^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^8}\right)$$ On the other hand, we have
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{\log(n)}{n}=\gamma _1-\gamma _1(x+1)$$ where appear the generalized Stieltjes constant.

Using, as a reference $x=10^3$ gives as a rationalized number
$C=-\frac{15}{206}$ which can be neglected.

Comment: Note that $C=\gamma_1$.